# How do I prove that this function is a measure?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, solution-verification

I have the following problem:

> Let $(\Omega, \mathfrak{A}, \mu)$ be a measurespace and let $f:\Omega \rightarrow [0,+\infty]$ be a nonegative simple function, i.e. $f(\Omega)=\{b_1,...b_s\}$. We define for $a\in \mathfrak{A}$ $$\int_A fd\mu=\int_\Omega \chi_A f d\mu$$. Show that the function $$A\mapsto \int_A fd\mu$$ is a measure.

My idea was the following:

**Proof**

We need to check the following two points. First it is easy to see that $$\emptyset \mapsto \int_\emptyset f d\mu=0$$But now let $I$ be a countable index set and let $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}\in \mathfrak{A}$ such that $A_i \cap A_j=\emptyset$ if $i\neq j$. Now consider $$\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \in \mathfrak{A}$$ and look at $$\int_{\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i} f d\mu=\int_\Omega f \chi_{\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i} d\mu\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)$$Let us remark that $$\chi_{\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i}(x)\leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty \chi_{A_i} (x)\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(2)$$ but since the $A_i$'s are disjoint we have indeed $$\chi_{\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i}=1 \Leftrightarrow x\in A_i$$ for some $i\in I$. Therefore from this fact we have equality in $(2)$.Then we have $$\int_\Omega f \chi_{\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i} d\mu=\int_\Omega f \cdot \sum_{i=1}^\infty \chi_{A_i}d\mu=\int_\Omega \left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty f\chi_{A_i}\right) d\mu$$. But now since we can swap the integrals and the sum we get $$\int_\Omega \left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty f\chi_{A_i}\right) d\mu=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \int_\Omega f\chi_{A_i} d\mu=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \int_{A_i} f d\mu\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(3)$$Now putting $(1)$ and $(3)$ together gives the sigma additivity.

I'm not sure if this works like this. could someone have a look maybe?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hello. What exactly are you not sure about?

Comment: Hello, so on the whole I'm not sure if that's even possible. I have my doubts about two points. Firstly, I have never used that the function is positive and simple, which makes me a little suspicious. In addition, I am not quite sure whether the argument in (2) is correct or whether we really have an equality.

Comment: It is in my opinion worth to add an exercise which I find more instructive than your original question. Let $(\Omega,\mathfrak A,\mu)$ be a signed measure space (not necessarily of finite total measure), and let $f$ be $\mu$-integrable (i.e. $f\in L^1(|\mu|)$). Show that $A\mapsto \int_A f d\mu$ defines a measure on $(\Omega,\mathfrak A)$ absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\mu$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure of your proof is correct, but it has huge leaps that **need** explanation. First, you give the inequality
$$\mathbf{1}_{\cup_iA_i}(x)\leq\sum_i \mathbf{1}_{A_i}(x)$$
If you're going to state this fact, you *must* explain why this holds for any countable collection of sets. You also need to show why, in the case that the $A_i$ s are disjoint, this inequality becomes an equality. Another massive gap is

> But now since we can swap the integrals and the sum...

**WHY??** Why can we swap the integral and the sum? Big hint - use the fact that $f$ is non-negative and simple!

To help you guide your thinking, here is an alternate proof. To avoid messy subscripts I will write the indicator function of the set $S$ as $\mathbf{1}(S)$. I.e $\mathbf{1}(S)(x)=1$ for $x\in S$ and $0$ otherwise.

---

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space and let $\varphi$ be a non-negative simple function:
$$\varphi=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\mathbf{1}(E_i)$$
Define the mapping
$$\nu(A)=\int_{A}\varphi\mathrm d\mu=\int_X \varphi \cdot \mathbf{1}(A)\mathrm d\mu$$
Let's show $\nu$ is a measure on $(X,\Sigma)$. The requirements $\nu:\Sigma\to [0,\infty]$ and $\nu(\emptyset)=0$ are very easily checked, so let's now check countable disjoint additivity. First, we can remark that
$$\nu(A)=\int_X \varphi\cdot \mathbf{1}(A) \mathrm d\mu = \int_X \sum_{i=1}^n\left(\mathbf{1}(A)\cdot a_i\mathbf{1}(E_i)\right) \mathrm d\mu$$
It is very easily checked that for any two sets $A,B$ that $\mathbf{1}(A)\cdot\mathbf{1}(B)=\mathbf{1}(A\cap B)$, and hence
$$\nu(A)=\int_X \sum_{i=1}^na_i\mathbf{1}(A\cap E_i)\mathrm d\mu$$
Since this is a finite sum, we have no problems interchanging summation with integration.
$$\nu(A)=\int_X \sum_{i=1}^na_i\mathbf{1}(A\cap E_i)\mathrm d\mu=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \int_X \mathbf{1}(A\cap E_i)\mathrm d\mu=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\mu(A\cap E_i)$$
Since the integrand is simple. So, let $\{F_j\}_j$ be a countable collection of disjoint sets. Then
$$\nu\left(\cup_j F_j\right)=\sum_{i=1}^na_i\mu\big(E_i\cap (\cup_jF_j)\big)$$
Using elementary set algebra,
$$E_i\cap(\cup_j F_j)=\cup_j(E_i\cap F_j)$$
Thus
$$\nu(\cup_j F_j)=\sum_{i=1}^na_i\mu\big(\cup_j(E_i\cap F_j)\big)$$
Since the sets $\{F_j\}_j$ are disjoint, the sets $\{E_i\cap F_j\}_j$ certainly are as well, for any fixed $i$, and since $\mu$ is a measure, it has countable disjoint additivity,
$$\nu(\cup_j F_j)=\sum_{i=1}^na_i\sum_j\mu(E_i\cap F_j)$$
Now we can interchange the order of summation (**why?**) and hence
$$\nu(\cup_j F_j)=\sum_j\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^na_i\mu(E_i\cap F_j)}_{=\nu(F_j)} \\ \nu(\cup_j F_j)=\sum_j\nu(F_j)$$
Done.

Comment: Hello Thank you for your huge answer. Sure I should explain the point with the inequality resp. equality. But to the other point of swapping integrals and sums we know that for nonnegative simple functions we have $$\int_\Omega (f_1+f_2)d\mu=\int_\Omega f_1 d\mu +\int_\Omega f_2 d\mu$$ so is it enough to use this in order to swap my integrals and sum?

Comment: So I mean that maybe one could rewrite the thing as $$\int_\Omega \left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty f\chi_{A_i}\right) d\mu=\int_\Omega \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n f\chi_{A_i}\right) d\mu$$. Then we would be done if we could swap the integral with the limit right?

Comment: Could I define $$g_n(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n f\chi_{A_i}$$ then since $f$ is nonegative also $g_n(x)$ is nonnegative. Futhermore we remark that $$\sum_{i=1}^n f\chi_{A_i}(x)-\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} f\chi_{A_i}(x)=-f\chi_{A_{n+1}}(x)\leq 0$$. Therefore we have a growing sequence of nonegative mesurable functions and we can apply the monotone convergence theorem of B.Levi which allows us to swap the integral and the limit, i.e. $$\int_\Omega \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n f\chi_{A_i} d\mu=lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_\Omega \sum_{i=1}^n f\chi_{A_i}$$ and for finite sums we can swap integals and sums

Comment: would this proof the point with swapping sum and integral?

Comment: @Wave Exactly. The monotone increasing convergence theorem is the key. All of the summands are non-negative and simple (hence integrable) so the MICT applies.

Comment: oh wow perfect. Thank you very much, so now the only crucial point left is the equality. I will try to prove this by myself. Thanks for your help I appreciate that!